# Shell script to remove all files inside a folder except one

Tags: bash, scripts

I am writing a shell script and want to delete everything from a folder with exception of one file.

This code does exactly what I am looking for:

```
rm -r -v subfolder/!("file")
```

First, from the shell script, I can not use directly the (), I found by searching that I should change it to: `/(file/)`

So in my script I wrote:

```
rm -r -v subfolder/!/("file"/)
```

But, when I run the script it keeps giving me the following error:

```
rm: cannot remove 'subfolder/!(file)': No such file or directory
```

I am running the script from the same folder as when I do the first bash command (the "subfolder" is a present folder in the current location of the bash and also the script is placed there in the same current location).

Complete script name of the file "Allclean" is:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ${0%/*} || exit 1    # Run from this directory

    # Source tutorial clean functions
. $WM_PROJECT_DIR/bin/tools/CleanFunctions
shopt -s extglob 

echo "\n
Cleaning case (Transilient Scalar Transport Equation)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"
echo "        - Deleting 0 folder"
rm -f -r 0
echo "        - Removing constant folder content except transportProperties"
cd constant
rm -r -v constant/!("transportProperties")
```

When I run `rm -r -v constant/!("transportProperties")` from the bash works properly. When I run `./Allclean` I get the following error:

```
./Allclean: 6: ./Allclean: shopt: not found


Cleaning case (Transilient Scalar Transport Equation)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        - Deleting 0 folder
        - Removing constant folder content except transportProperties
./Allclean: 16: ./Allclean: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: *"i found by searching that i should change it"* can you provide a link? it is more likely that all you needed to do was enable extended globbing inside your script (`shopt -s extglob`)

Comment: ufff.. good question where i saw it..but it still does not work with the shopt -s extglob
i get " ./Allclean: 16: ./Allclean: Syntax error: "(" unexpected"
Allclean is the run script

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include at least the relevant portion of your script

Comment: i just edited whit the extra information, from what you asked before i read it from here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153862/remove-all-files-directories-except-for-one-file

Comment: Does your script have a bash shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) as the first line? from what interactive shell are you executing `./Allclean`?

Comment: yes, sorry i forgot to add it.

Comment: It appears you are trying to use bash's `extglob` inside a `/bin/sh` script. `sh` (aka `dash`) does not support this feature. Change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

use find with the delete option

```
yiheng@DESKTOP-LIJQMSN:/mnt/c/Users/ihen$ ls folder/
a  b  c  d  e
yiheng@DESKTOP-LIJQMSN:/mnt/c/Users/ihen$ find folder/ -mindepth 1 -not -path folder/d
folder/a
folder/b
folder/c
folder/e
yiheng@DESKTOP-LIJQMSN:/mnt/c/Users/ihen$ find folder/ -mindepth 1 -not -path folder/d -delete
yiheng@DESKTOP-LIJQMSN:/mnt/c/Users/ihen$ ls folder/
d
yiheng@DESKTOP-LIJQMSN:/mnt/c/Users/ihen$
```